# Find default pip index-url

Tags: pip

Is there a way to find which url(s) my pip command will look for when running something like `pip install <package>`?

You can configure files like `.pip/pip.conf` and `.pypirc` to modify that default but I'd like to know if there is a way to know the mirror priority.

Can I look for something specific running a command with the verbose flag (`-v`)?

Comment: `pip` doesn't automatically use mirrors, you have to list and use them manually. Without any configuration `pip` install packages from https://pypi.org which uses CDN instead of mirroring.

Comment: Maybe mirror is the wrong word, I mean index-urls

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The help message for the `install` command will include the default value next to the `--index-url` option.

```
$ pip install -h
...
  -i, --index-url <url>       Base URL of Python Package Index (default https://pypi.python.org/simple).
...
```

The message may vary slightly depending on your version of `pip`. If an alternate address is [configured](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file), it will appear in that help message.

```
$ cat ~/.config/pip/pip.conf
[global]
index-url = https://my.local.mirror.com/simple
$ pip install -h
...
  -i, --index-url <url>       Base URL of Python Package Index (default https://my.local.mirror.com/simple).
...
```

Comment: to find the config file use `pip config -v list`

Comment: @Verthais, it doesn't work for pip 8.1.2 we use on some of our envs

Answer (score 22):

`pip3 config list` prints the config. Config file locations are documented https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file. For me, it was located in `/etc/pip.conf`.

Comment: For people like who are trying to figure out where a certain setting is coming from: `pip3 config edit` will also show all config file locations (*except* config files in virtual environments). My impression is that all these files *together* somehow affect the "current" config. That is, I had set `foo=bar` in my `~/.pip/pip.conf`. But I was in my venv in whose `pip.conf` I had *not* set `foo=bar` and `pip3 config list` *still* showed `foo=bar`. So if you're wondering why a certain config setting is getting applied / not applied, make sure to check *all* config files!

Comment: You can also check out the pip source-code at https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/0945809afc70cb591c07dfca4b4f8d23eef63e65/src/pip/_internal/configuration.py#L71

Comment: What if I am stuck using an old version of pip that doesn't have the config command?

Comment: Get only the global.index-url: python -m pip config get "global.index-url"

Comment: `pip config list` shows the result after they're layered together, but `pip config debug` will additionally show where the source of each configuration comes from (env var, config file(s), etc).