# Jenkins - Docker Build time

Tags: docker, jenkins

How can I minimize the build time of Dockerfile's while running the pipelines in Jenkins?

I've read somewhere, its best to remove the images and free up space when the pipelines have been executed successfully. It works all well, but when the next commit initiates the pipeline, it rebuilds the complete images which takes a lot of time to rebuild again (~ 5mins). If the images are not removed, it picks the image from the cache and rebuilds in no time.

I want to understand what other experienced people recommend to lower the build time?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I usually do:

- Build and tag custom Docker images with common steps between job execution. For instance, if you are building a Python project, have an custom image based Python image with "heavy to install" (e.g: numpy if required build from source) dependencies pre-installed.
- Add an http cache for everything that the build downloads.
  If you want to make it completely transparent you'll need an http proxy (e.g: squid) and set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables on docker build pointing it.

Comment: How do you add http cache for pip installations?

Comment: You can either do it using a http proxy (e.g: squid) and configure docker to use that proxy (https://elegantinfrastructure.com/docker/ultimate-guide-to-docker-http-proxy-configuration/); or setup an internal pipy repository (e.g: nexus) and use a custom index-url (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471899/520275)