# Which url does pip install get it's files from?

Tags: python, security, firewall

I'm working on a secure system where internet access is restricted. My company will let my install python and libraries, but they only allow the unblocking of specific urls temporarily. So I need to know what urls do I need to unblock to install python and what urls I need to unblock to execute

**pip install pandas**

**pip install requests**

**pip install xlrd**

among others.

Alternatively I would also be happy if I could just find a url to manually install each library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find default pip index-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100576/find-default-pip-index-url)

Comment: Have you considered to manually download the packages on a different machine, move the packages to the target host and then install them? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300321/150978 for details.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found `sodim.dev` . It does have some accuracy issues (i had tried this couple months back), but the end result has download urls, source code urls etc. I had similar challenge in the past where i had to work without internet. It might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The default pip server is https://pypi.org/simple
For your use case, I would recommend installing a local pip server where you can manage the packages internally and all users can download them from there, there are several examples all over google.