# What's the correct index-url for PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pypi

I am trying to install packages from `requirements.txt` on a machine with a different `global.index` and different `search.index`. I am using the `--index-url` option but I get an error.

```
$ pip3 install --index-url https://pypi.org/ -r requirements.txt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement annotated-types==0.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for annotated-types==0.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

I had Python `3.8` but I updated to `3.11` to check if there was a version incompatibility but I get the same error. Is there a different URL I should use? I tried https://pypi.org/projects/ with `projects` at the end but it failed at the next package.

Comment: `pip install --help` says `https://pypi.org/simple`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find default pip index-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100576/find-default-pip-index-url)

Comment: I spent an hour trying to search why the issue occurred. I even went to PyPI. I think you need to realize that there are some many paths that searching could lead to. I don't write questions unless I really need to. It takes 20 minutes because I have to make sure that I provide all the info and not include any personal information.

Comment: Sorry, think I might be getting burnt out by seeing too many similar questions.  Difficult to remember what it's like learning when everything seems new and it's difficult to "join the dots up".

Answer (score -2):

The right index-url for pip3 is https://files.pythonhosted.org - it basically hosts everything there is on pypi

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://files.pythonhosted.org/ egg` fails.  that site might store lots of relevant files, but not in a manner suitable for use with pip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).